# convert int to date to add a dayn and convert to int back

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have int value with YYYYMM. I want to:
1. convert it into datetime 
2. add one day DATEADD(Day, +1, @date) 
3. convert it back into int

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql

Comment: what's the need to use `DATEADD` ? if you have `YYYYMM` as input, you'll always have 2 as "output day" !

Comment: By the way, what kind of "int" do you want as output ? Could you show an example with real input and output ?

Comment: Can explain what you are trying to achieve? because at the end your answer will be integer value + 1.

Comment: Why step 3? When you convert it back in step three, you'll lose the work from step 2. What you **really** need to do, is convert the column to a datetime.

Comment: I need to insert datatime values as int, because I can't convert all column to datetime - it'll brake many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice exercise and I hope it works out for you...

```
declare @date date

declare @newDate date

set @date = convert(date, '20100101')

set @newdate = DateAdd(dd, 1, @Date)

select @date

select @newdate

select convert(int, convert(varchar, @newdate, 112))  -- this is your final conversion back to int
```

Comment: Note, this is missing the initial conversion from `int`. You can just convert to `varchar` inline, though: `set @date = convert(date, convert(varchar, 20100101))`

Answer (score 0):

If your initial int is, say, 201310 (October 2013), then what I think you want is this:

```
select convert(datetime, rtrim(201310 * 100 + 1))
```

The function RTRIM is a trick to convert int to string type.

The result is this:

```
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

If you don't want to use RTRIM, the command below will get you the same result:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(char, 201310 * 100 + 1))
```