# Need to convert INT to value I can DIFF against

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the below query where the original convert was written for another table with a different date value.  The [YMDRCVD] value is (INT, null). I'm using SQL management studio 14 and receiving an Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime error message.

```
SELECT
   Year(CH.[YMDRCVD]) as [Receipt date Year], 
   Month(CH.[YMDRCVD]) as [Receipt Date Month],
   COUNT(*) as [Count of Claims],
   AVG(convert(numeric(19,2), DATEDIFF(day, CH.[YMDRCVD], CH.[YMDTRANS]))) as [Average Days from Receipt to Initial Finalized] ,
   SUM(
   CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(day, CH.[YMDRCVD], CH.[YMDTRANS]) > 10 THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) as [Count Processed in > 10 Days]
FROM [SERVICE_X] CH WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
   CH.[YMDRCVD] >= '1/1/2016'
   AND CH.[YMDRCVD] < '6/1/2016'
   AND DATEDIFF(day, CH.[YMDRCVD], CH.[YMDTRANS]) < 20
   AND DATEDIFF(day, CH.[YMDRCVD], CH.[YMDTRANS]) >= 0 
GROUP BY Year(CH.[YMDRCVD]), 
   Month(CH.[YMDRCVD])
ORDER BY 
   Year(CH.[YMDRCVD]), 
   Month(CH.[YMDRCVD])
```

Comment: If `YMDRCVD` is an int datatype, what do you expect to happen when you try to use Datetime functions like DATEDIFF on it?

Comment: why don't you convert it to `decimal(38,2)` and check?

Comment: Column name YMD leads me to believe it's in the 20160516 [(ISO 8601)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you are trying to call a date function on a value not of data type date / datetime.

You need to convert [YMDRCVD] to date time.

Check out this post: [Convert INT to DATETIME (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to decode the date:

For `YYYYMMDD`:

```
 DATEFROMPARTS( FLOOR([YMDRCVD]/10000), FLOOR([YMDRCVD]/100)%100, [YMDRCVD]%100 )
```