# Convert an Int to a date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert an integer field to an actual date field. Someone created a "date" field that just sticks in a "date" that is actually an integer. I'm trying to convert it to an actual date.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
CAST(CAST(last_purch_date AS CHAR) AS DATE) as Create,
CAST( last_purch_date as datetime) as Created,
convert(datetime,last_purch_date) as Created1,
ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8),last_purch_date)) as PleaseDearGodWORK
```

Comment: Do you know the exact format of the date? Depending on that, you could either convert it to string and then datetime, or parse it manually.

Comment: What does the value represent? Have you got an example of an integer, and the date value you expect that value to relate to? Also what version of SQL Server - if pre-2008 you won't have access to DATE or TIME types.

Comment: Edit your question and include what the integer looks like.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple cast as date could work

```
Select cast(cast(20161011 as varchar(8)) as date)
```

Returns

```
2016-10-11
```

If your data is suspect, you could also use Try_Convert()

```
Select Try_Convert(date,cast(2610 as varchar(8)))
```

Returns

```
NULL
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @donviti see updated answer .. Try_Convert   I am also assuming the int is YYYYMMDD

Comment: working code: Try_Convert(date,cast(last_purch_date as varchar(8)))

Comment: @donviti Just check out the NULL's  Seems like some data scrub may be required

Comment: Just remember that Try_Convert will return a NULL value on failed converts so you should probably check which ones failed to ensure there is no missing/invalid data.

Comment: Yeah, it's a fleet software.  I have no control over the data so I have to deal with what I have.  Thank you very much @John

Comment: all rows were returned

Comment: @donviti What is a sample value ?

Comment: @donviti  Is it n Seconds/Days from a say 1/1/1980 or

Comment: YYYYMMDD format  20160101  your code outputs 2016-01-01

Comment: @donviti  Great!  I misunderstood your comment of all records returned, I thought all were null.   Well done.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(8),[columname],101))
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.