# How to convert numeric number into datatime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, bigint, sql-convert

I need help to convert a bigint value into a datetime value using SQL Server.
Example value `634254092190100000`

How to convert to datetime value?

So far this is what I have but getting an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

```
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 632979854880200000) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: If you could share what date that should be and why it would go a long way to letting others help you. As it sits we have no idea what that represents.

Comment: @mvlaicevich the number here is not like the one in that link.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981520/convert-an-int-to-a-date-field?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do :

```
SELECT CAST((YOURVALUE- 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS datetime)
```

For exemple :

```
SELECT CAST((635307578922100000 - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS datetime)
```

Gives `"2014-03-18 16:44:52"`

Knowing that :
- 599266080000000000 is 19000101
- 864000000000 is the number of ms / day
- 599266080000000000 / 864000000000 = 693595 /365 = 1900 (aprox)

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql for further details about starting day for each datetime type family...

Comment: 24 hours/day * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute * 1000 milliseconds/second = 86400000 milliseconds/day by my reckoning. The OP used a base date of 1970-01-01 which you don't seem to account for. At least the OP is happy with the answer.

Comment: I know, I told the OP about that... But With 19700101, I got out of range message... Meaning the OP was wrong about that (too) : the bigint date value starts from 1900 and not from 1970.