# How to convert Big Int into Datetime style 109

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How to convert the Big Int into datetime with style 109 that starts with 
`mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM`

632979854880200000 is the Big INT

`select Convert(Datetime,((632979854880200000 - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000),109) AS Datetime
from Abc`

Comment: Please add a little more detail, such as what the math in the convert statement is attempting, as well as expected results.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491686/how-to-convert-numeric-number-into-datatime) is a different question. Why a duck?

Comment: @HABO Wish I saw your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
select ViaConvert = Convert(varchar(30),Convert(Datetime,((632979854880200000 - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000.0)),109)
      ,ViaFormat  = Format(Convert(Datetime,((632979854880200000 - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000.0)),'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

**Returns**

```
ViaConvert                    ViaFormat
Nov  1 2006  1:44:48:017PM    Nov 01 2006 01:44:48 PM
```