# Convert integer to date as MM/DD/YYYY like from 20200926 to 09/26/2020?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert number to date from 20200926 to 09/26/2020, where date_key is the date col in table. The below code does not return the output as 09/26/2020 it's returning value in the same format.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_key,101)       
FROM table
```

Comment: No, because the style format only works when you pass a date object in, not your self defined number date. And this question has been asked many many times before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an Int to a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981520/convert-an-int-to-a-date-field)

Comment: StoreDatesinDateTimeColumns

Comment: convert(date,convert(varchar(10),date_key,101)) as Date This but does not let me do MM/DD/YYYY gives me 2020-09-26

Comment: What does *to some extend* mean?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a string and then to a date and back to a string with the right format:

```
select convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(20200926 as varchar(255)) as date), 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your number format is already in YYYYMMDD format, so converting to date datetype is easier.

First you are converting to CHAR(8) to get string representation and then converting to DATE value. Then choose the format for display.

[More info on CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT convert(NVARCHAR(10),convert(date,convert(NCHAR(8),tdate)),101)
FROM
(
VALUES (20200926)
) as t(tdate)
```

```
+------------+
|  dateval   |
+------------+
| 09/26/2020 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Made alternative solution. I guess less readable for some and more for others.

```
print datefromparts(20200926/10000,20200926%10000/100,20200926%100)
```