# How to convert round number to data and time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, sql-timestamp

Two Column in table tblpress

> ```
> Date          Time
> 20160307      120949
> 20160307      133427
> ```

Need to be select below the format:

> `07-03-2016      12:09:49
>   07-03-2016       13:34 27`

or

> ```
> 03-March-2016   12:09: 49 PM
> 03-March-2016   01:34: 27 PM
> ```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: i have use ms sql server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

for the desired output format

Comment: What's data type in `Date` and `Time`? `Int`?

Comment: date and time char

Comment: "date and time char" There's your problem right there - Date should be stored as Date and Time should be stored as Time - What you really should do is fix the table structure.

Comment: i need just select

Comment: @khan better write a function to convert the type from int to date and time and then call the function in your select query

Comment: @khan posted an answer check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `CAST/CONVERT` will help you:

```
SELECT
  CAST('20160307' AS date),
  CAST(STUFF(STUFF('120949',3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS time)
```

And convert for out:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(20),NormalDate,105) OutDate, -- Italian style
  CONVERT(varchar(20),NormalTime,108) OutTime -- hh:mi:ss
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CAST([Date] AS date) NormalDate,
      CAST(STUFF(STUFF([Time],3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS time) NormalTime
    FROM YourTable
  ) q
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And you can use [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd-MM-yyyy'),
  FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
select format(cast([Date] as date),'dd-MMMM-yyyy') as [Date],
TIMEFROMPARTS(LEFT([Time],2), SUBSTRING([Time],3,2), RIGHT([Time],2), 0,0) as [Time]
```

Comment: for the output +1 but thats i think is not a robust way

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to create a function :

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetDateTimeFromInteger]
(
   @intDate int,
   @intTime int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @DT_datetime datetime = NULL,
  @str_date varchar(11),
  @str_time varchar(8)
if(@intDate is not null and @intDate > 0)
begin
  select @str_date = CAST( cast(@intDate as varchar(8)) AS date)
  if @intTime=0
     select @str_time ='000000'
  else
     select @str_time = right('0'+CONVERT(varchar(11),@intTime),6)
  select @str_time = 
   SUBSTRING(@str_time,1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@str_time,3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@str_time,5,2)

  select @DT_datetime = CAST(@str_date+' '+@str_time as datetime)
 end
 -- Return the result of the function
 RETURN @DT_datetime

 END
```

and then call it in select like :

```
declare @next_run_date int, @next_run_time int
select @next_run_date = 20160307
select @next_run_time = 130949

SELECT  @next_run_date inputdate,
                @next_run_time inputtime,
                dbo.udfGetDateTimeFromInteger(@next_run_date, @next_run_time) outputdatetime
```

Output will be like :

```
inputdate   inputtime   outputdatetime
20160307    130949      2016-03-07 13:09:49.000
```

Comment: "best" way? Why is this best? Even if creating a function might be good, this is not the function that is best, right?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Completly agreed I never said that this funcion is the best :).What I meant was to reduce the code overload in the actual place

Answer (score 0):

You said those are numbers, right? You can use datetimefromparts (or datetime2fromparts). ie:

```
select 
 datetimefromparts(
  [date]/10000,
  [date]%10000/100,
  [date]%100,
  [time]/10000,
  [time]%10000/100,
  [time]%100,0)
from tblpress;
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c35529ea2a664fc6ac8ced2919390d6a)

Note that naming fields like that and also storing date and time like that is a bad idea.

I later noticed it was char fields:

```
select 
  cast([date] as datetime) +
  cast(stuff(stuff([time],5,0,':'),3,0,':') as datetime)
from tblpress;
```