# trying to cast an int data type into date

Tags: sql, date, casting, integer

How do I convert `int` to `date` using cast in the format setting below.

`month` column is an `int` type that want to be converted to `date`.

```
SELECT x y z
  FROM table 
  WHERE name = 'S'
    AND lastname = 'Y'
    AND month= startdate
```

Comment: what about year and day?

Comment: right, it includes day month and year in this format 20200103

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What data type is `startdate`?

Comment: @OEGM2002 can you tag your question with correct sql database? sql-server etc... also does [Convert INT to DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql) help?

Comment: I'm trying to change the month which is an int datatype to date/time so I can select a start date from a calendar

Comment: @huMptyduMpty kinda don't k now how to incorporate it with my code

Comment: @OEGM2002 As with huMpty duMpty's comment you will want to use a combination of cast and convert per his link. Using cast only on an int datatype will only add those days on to the 1900-01-01 datetime

Comment: @Shmiel startdate should be datetime because i will be using it in ssrs so i want it to be a calendar option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you (as you said in the comments):

```sql
create table test(
  date_as_int int,
  date_as_date date
);
insert into test(date_as_int, date_as_date)
values (20220705, '20220705'),
(20220704, '20220604'),
(20200507, '20200707');

select * 
from test
where cast(cast(date_as_int as char(8)) as date) >= date_as_date
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15444b25c0b45ead8f18f66506b0e610)

So in your case change `and month >= stardate` to `and cast(cast(month as char(8)) as date) >= startdate`.

Comment: I'm using mysql and month is already declared as an integer. also I already have a select statement so is it going to be a nested query then?

Comment: @OEGM2002 Is month a column with only the month?

Comment: monthid is a column with yyyy/m/d

Comment: no I'm trying to get a result based on the selected date

Comment: So this means you want to compare selected date (`startdate`) with `month` which is a `date` but saved as `int`? So you can just do the `where` as in answer without `month()`

Comment: So just change it to `>=`

Comment: @OEGM2002 I edited my answer please check if it works for you, if yes please [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if not please let me know why and I'll see if I can help you.