# Convert an INT field to DATE field

Tags: sql, date, integer

Is it possible to change an INT field to a DATE field?

I have the below script - however, I would like the `[DelDateKey]` to be displayed as a date DD/MM/YYYY.

```
select[DelDateKey],
    sum([Order]), sum([ACS]), sum([Pick]) , sum([DIS])
  FROM 
   [pw].[WA].[Sales]
   WHERE  [IdKey]= 1
and [DelDateKey] in (select distinct top 7 [DeldateKey] from [pw].[WA].[Sales] order by [DeldateKey] desc ) 

   GROUP BY [DelDateKey]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to cast an int data type into date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870882/trying-to-cast-an-int-data-type-into-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
CONVERT(datetime, CAST([DelDateKey] AS CHAR(10)), 101)
```